# How to test if a variable is declared?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

I can test if a property exists like this:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
-(void)testcachedPublicFeedExists
{
    objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty([store class], "cachedPublicFeed");
    XCTAssertTrue(prop);
}
```

But how do I test if a class variable like `cachedVar` exists?

```
@interface FTDataStoreBase : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *cachedVar;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these methods `class_getInstanceVariable` or `class_getClassVariable`.

```
- (void)testcachedVarExists
{
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([store class], "cachedVar");
    XCTAssertTrue(ivar);
}
```

Learn more at [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-Reference-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: Are you sure this would work? I solved it this way: `Ivar prop = class_getInstanceVariable([store class], "cachedPublicFeed");
    XCTAssertTrue(prop);`

Comment: @Hooman yeah, I meant it but wrote something else. Edited the answer.